# What replaces folk psychology concepts when taking neurosciences serious?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, psychology, neurophilosophy, translation

When neuroscience and neuroscientists tell us<sup>1</sup> that specific kinds of  concepts (entities and processes) of good ol' [folk psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_psychology) don't really exist (in a scientifically meaningful manner)

- thoughts (as something ephemeral going on in a person's mind or brain) and beliefs (something a bit less ephemeral)
- feelings, emotions, moods
- desires, intentions, motivations
- values

which alternatives do they specifically give us, i.e. which other kinds of specific entities and processes (in their own terms)? And which translation rules do they give us?

The same question could be asked with respect to (scientific) psychology and psychologists, but their terminology much more overlaps with the terminology of folk psychology and translatability seems in reach.

---

<sup>1</sup> normal, common people, folk psychologists

Comment: I feel the question bowdlerises neuroscience. If thoughts do not exist 'in a scientifically meaningful manner' then what neuroscientists think can be ignored. I'm not sure any of them suggest such a thing. It would be odd to do so since on analysis the only phenomenon science studies are thoughts. Most are naive realists so they have no right to the high-ground on this issue.

Comment: @PeterJ: I can follow your objection - and did in no way want to bowdlerise neuroscience (even though I don't understand completely what you mean: Do you mean that I insinuate something on them?) Nevertheless: When neuroscientist don't  deny the existence of "thoughts" and agree that "thoughts" belong to their ontology and that they deal with them - how to they "define" them in their own terms?

Comment: @PeterJ: I should have made clear what I mean with "thought" and did so in an edit to my question.

Comment: The question is a good one, but I feel it is not correct to say anyone proposes that concepts do not exist in a scientifically meaningful sense. They are not empirical phenomena so the nature of their existence is not a matter for science. Neuroscience has nothing to say about consciousness and cannot even find it. Neuroscientists are free to speculate on the weekends but it ain't science. Some neuroscientists take the same view.  . ,

Comment: @PeterJ: That's where the problems arise: You say "thoughts" (for example) are not empirical phenomena, let alone "consciousness". I agree that neuroscientists don't have to deal with "consciousness" (because they cannot grasp it in a scientifically meaningful sense) but they possibly accept "thoughts" as empirical phenomena. So how do they integrate them in their theoretical and conceptual framework - without having to know or discuss the "nature of their existence"?

Comment: I assume that one can treat "thoughts" and "consciousness" independently: thoughts don't have to be conscious, consciousness doesn't have to be thoughtful.

Comment: The word 'empirical' usually implies sensory data. Thoughts would not fall into this category. I'd agree that thoughts are not consciousness. They are what consciousness is conscious of. Neuroscience accepts first-person reports of thoughts as empirical data, but not the thoughts themselves. If they studied thoughts and consciousness directly as non-empirical phenomena they would be leaving neuroscience for mysticism. .

Comment: Neuroscience, as any science, is limited by it's theoretical framework. It has a language derived from that framework wherein certain words do not make sense (_yet_).

Comment: Do you equally consider physicists to be telling us solid objects do not really exist? (Because the fact things are made of atoms means our ordinary meaning of solid is only an approximation.)  and do you demand they tell you what the notion of solid has been replaced with?  If not, then you need a different way of phrasing the question that is less of an oversimplification.

Comment: Also nobody has to accept a "non-overlapping magisteria" argument from mystics about thoughts.  As a psychologist, I clearly studied thoughts, even though I had to access them through behavior and reporting.  That I was not a mystic did not make psychological investigations impossible or meaningless.  The same is obviously the case regarding neurology.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on https://psychology.stackexchange.com/ since it also deals with neuroscience? I doubt the latter field denies the validity of the "higher level" psychological constructs much... although it may be true for some of them. Anyway, you're likely to get more substantive answers there.

Answer (score 1):

The general and blurry line between [folk psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_psychology) and scientifically rigorous [psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology) is one, first and foremost, about representations in a presumed (mostly) realist metaphysical position about the world. What the behavioral sciences purport to give is more accurate, more confident propositions about the world than the back-of-the-envelope calculations that our naive intellects are capable of. Some simple examples suffice.

A human speaking strangely might be seen in some cultures as being possessed. Perhaps their words are coming out strangely, and they aren't acting like themselves. A folk psychology in pre-literate society might allow a person to draw the conclusion, this strange speaking of tongues is a supernatural event, and this person is blessed by the gods. It's not an entirely strange thought historically speaking. History is rife with accounts exactly like this, and particularly in the time and place the observations are made, it's a viable explanation. Remember that one of the chief functions of human cognition is to provide explanations of the world.

A psychologist, however, will look at that same set of observations and might come to a distinct conclusion using the theory and methods of science. For instance, the study of odd language use might lead the psychologist to consider the natural phenomenon of [aphasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasia). To narrow down the diagnosis, tests can be run to determine, for instance, whether this aphasia is a byproduct of a stroke in a particular region of the brain using [fMRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_magnetic_resonance_imaging) technology. In fact, it might be possible to narrow the aphasia down to something as specific as [Broca's aphasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressive_aphasia). The conjecture then can be vetted by peers of a similar skill-set, and a consensus can be built using the [medical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_model). Maybe a pharmacological solution even exists and can be administered that can reduce or eliminate the aphasia.

So, there are two starkly different methods. One is the hey, I-saw-on-TV method, and the other is process built on more than a hundred years of academic, industrial, and professional development.

Both address these topics:

> - thoughts and beliefs
>
>   - feelings, emotions, moods
>   - desires, intentions, motivations
>   - values

but one approaches the problem from a position of [naive realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_realism) about the mind, and the other from a [scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method). Now, is [neuropsychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuropsychology) really independent from psychology generally? Absolutely not. Psychology benefits from questions about personality, adjustment, learning, and the physical basis of the mind. Neuropsychology and neurology provide a rigorous explanation of the mind from [materialist position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialism).

> which alternatives do they specifically give us, i.e. which other kinds of specific entities and processes? And which translation rules do they give us?
>
> The same question could be asked with respect to (scientific) psychology and psychologists, but their terminology much more overlaps with the terminology of folk psychology and translatability seems in reach.

These questions seem to presume a very formalist account of language, such as that folk psychological propositions are somehow distinct from psychological or neuropsychological propositions, and that the distinction is one of syntax. But the distinction of the nature of folk psychology versus scientific psychological discourse is primarily intended to be semantic in nature. One can express folk psychology using scientific terminology, and one can account for folk psychological accounts using science. Thus they differ not like one formal theory which can be translated into another formal theory by a metalanguage, but rather as two [holistically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holism) different beasts in the sense Rorty or Quine used. And there is no absolute distinction to the differences in discourse. One can point to a 4-year old and then to a professor emeritus of psychology and be certain the distinction will hold, but what of a slow graduate student who ekes through a program last in his class?

It is common to approach these philosophical questions from a formalist set of assumptions about language use, but in the end, as the [logical empiricists and positivists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism) found, [meaning is bigger than language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_grounding_problem).

Comment: @J D: Thanks for the answer. Your first example would be more convincing if you started not with folks from some strange (to us) culture or preliterate society. Since we live in a literate society where scientific psychology already entered (our) folk psychology to some degree it would be more interesting to compare - for example - how folk psychologists and scientific psychologists look at personal disorders.

Comment: In an ideal world neuroscience would be free of naivety in the way you describe. But most neuroscientists endorse naive realism and this is why their ideas on consciousness are not free of folk-psychology but are often examples of it.

Comment: @PeterJ: Well said!

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Fair criticism. Use your imagination and consider [conversion therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_therapy). Illiteracy can be applied to the notion of science equally plausibly. Religious fundamentalists tend to be highly scientifically illiterate. The point still stands.

Comment: I suspect most scientists are not good at philosophy of science. Their central occupation is called normal science by Kuhn, and that comports well with [Sturgeon's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law). I didn't purport that most scientists are free of naive realism. I believe that all people use naive realism in some form at some times. The fundamental dichotomization between self and world is incapable of being irradicated from thought entirely. Descartes didn't commit a category error, he merely endorsed a proclivity as all encompassing.

Comment: And you seem to presume that science happens primarily in the head of an individual. The business of science, as in the business of language, is a social reality, and the products of science and language are not owed to any one person, despite our egocentric natures. Einstein didn't invent any German or much math or science; he merely connected a few dots that were a byproduct of the social milieu.

Comment: @PeterJ Do you have source to substantiate the empirical claim that most neuroscientists endorse naive realism?

Comment: @JD I'm afraid not. But a few years as a subscriber to JCS is some sort of evidence and although there must be exceptions I've never read a neuroscientist who isn't one. Do you have some counter-examples?

Comment: @PeterJ The burden of the proof is on the claimant. Otherwise one sinks into the gish gallop which is rather poor form. Besides, your claim was "most", thus any number of specific examples likely wouldn't actually disprove the claim. It's clever of you to make claims that can't be disproved by small number of counterexamples, but telling you make claims without support.

Comment: @Jd I can only go on my experience, which makes it very clear that my comment was correct. You could easily confirm it by a quick survey. .

Comment: @PeterJ Ah, your experience. Okay.